# XmllSerializer.Serialize and returning raw xml

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I am using an XmlSerializer to serialize an object to xml.  After the object gets serialized, I end up with something like...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xml xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
</xml>
```

I need to have it return simply...

```
<xml></xml>
```

Is there a way to serialize xml without the extra information?  I realize strictly proper xml requires these additional elements, but I need the simpler form as I am appending these xml strings together to form a larger xml blob.

UPDATE

I was able to get the following code to work...

```
    public static string Serialize(object o)
    {
        XmlWriterSettings xws = new XmlWriterSettings();
        xws.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
        xws.Indent = true;

        XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        ns.Add(String.Empty, String.Empty);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        XmlWriter xmlw = XmlWriter.Create(sb, xws);
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(o.GetType());
        serializer.Serialize(xmlw, o, ns);
        xmlw.Flush();

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: What language: C#, Java?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C#, you can do something like this:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(object));
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();

using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter, new XmlWriterSettings() { OmitXmlDeclaration = true }))
{
    serializer.Serialize(writer, this, new XmlSerializerNamespaces() { "",""});
}
string xmlText = stringWriter.ToString();
```

Explanation:

`OmitXmlDeclaration = true` makes it remove the declaration.

`new XmlSerializerNamespaces() { "",""}` removes the namespaces.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I thought it would work but I get an error when an empty namespace is used.  I then looked that up on MSDN and see "The creation of an empty namespace and prefix pair is not supported", so I guess I will need to write a custom serializer or find a 3rd party library that will do it.  I really appreciate the answer however!  It got me close!

Comment: According to this [post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/thread/1c9e1f37-3647-49e2-bd6e-64e949b02fb6/?prof=required) (and several others), this does seem to work: `XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();  
ns.Add("", "");`

Comment: Yes, I was able to make it work after all.  I edited my original post with the code I am using.  Thanks for your help.